# Grouped bars have different spacing in Highcharts. Why?

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

I have a bar chart with one group of five items. Strangely, the distance between the bars within the same group is different. I tried out almost all imaginable settings as on the references list, but in vain.

[Here is the graph](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/megatrends/data/forest_change.php).

The PlotOptions code is this:

```
plotOptions:
{
  series:
  {
    borderWidth: 0,
    shadow: false,
    pointWidth: 10
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `pointWidth` property - your chart is to small for that value, remove that or change to something like ~7.

Comment: Thanks for that. But that doesn't help. I changed the size of the graph, as well as the pointWidth, but nothing helped.

Comment: Have you tried to use pointPadding? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPadding

Comment: Right, you have old Highcharts, take a look at actual rendering: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/50/

Comment: Very strange. When I use the CSV it creates the above problem. When the data are inserted, as in your example, directly into the Javscript , it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably you have some extra line at the end of file, check that.